# Android Studio Heap Dump Causing Network Disconnect

Tags: android, android-studio, hprof

I'm debugging an inherited codebase/VOIP app while the Android client is connected to the network. The Android client is a desk phone and connected to network via ethernet. I am using the Android Monitor in Android Studio to look for memory leaks. Curiously enough though, I am noticing that the app is disconnecting from the network whenever I generate a Heap Dump (HPROF).

Seems that debug tools like heap dumping should be benign (sort of like Star Trek's Prime Directive). Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: What do you see in the dump?  The tools do not cause the network to disconnect (I have never seen this happen in my uses).

Comment: I'm sorry, can you please clarify your question "what do you see in the dump"?  I see nothing unusual in the HPROFs.

Comment: It probably calls for more detailed debugging, and my networking knowledge is limited, but perhaps there is something in particular about the hprof dump accessing the device that is interfering with the app's network connection. Perhaps, the hprof dump is causing a socket timeout on the device side (like I said, a little debugging should turn up the reason for the disconnect).